# How to set image instead of boolean value?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I want to show image as a boolean value from a servlet to android app. Servlet will be uploaded to google app engine.
This is my servlet. "arrBool" value displays like some random value.

//

```
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    if (req.getParameterMap().containsKey("message"))
        message = req.getParameter("message");

    resp.getWriter().println("Server Said" + message);




    for (int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
        arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
            if(arrBool[i]==true) {
                resp.getWriter().print(arrBool);
            }
    }
```

and this is my android application file:

//

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://machougul01.appspot.com/listenforrestclient");
        client.AddParam("message", "Hello two World");
//        client.AddParam("arrBool", "textView1");


    try
    {
        client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        textView.setText(e.getMessage());
    }

    String response = client.getResponse();
    textView.setText(response);
}
```

Output shows "Server said: Hello two world" and arrBool value: "m9a9990a m9a9990"
I want to set arrBool value as image instead of m9a9990a. So whenever randomly values are selected if it is true then number of cars will be shown from 1 - 6 out of 6.
Please help me with this.

Comment: I didn't know that. I have just accepted some answers. SORRY

Comment: Forget about the code for now and focus on explaining exactly what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it.  I am completely confused by your statement that you want to convert an array of bools to an image - which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
resp.getWriter().print(arrBool);
```

To

resp.getWriter().print(String.valueOf(arrBool));

It will write a string in your response.

or you can change this

```
for (int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
        arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
            if(arrBool[i]==true) {
                resp.getWriter().print(arrBool);
            }
    }
```

To

```
for (int i=0; i<arrBool.length; i++) {
        arrBool[i] = r.nextBoolean();
            if(arrBool[i]==true) {
                resp.getWriter().print(1);
            }
    }
```

So when you read at response at client side you will get response line as
"Server said: Hello two world"
111

You can then parse string and no 1's or true's out and show or

Comment: Thanks. I did that, output comes as 11 or 1111 or 111111. But how can I change it to an image I want to show? Like instead of 1 I want to show an image.

Comment: I mean I don't want to show 1 as output, instead of that I want to display an image, which will output as one image or two or three images, like this. Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things you need to do.

First, there's a few import statements you'll need. Maybe you can use apache commons for the base64, this example uses xerces.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;
```

Next you need to create an image out of your booleans:

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(wid,hgt,BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_RGB);

```
final int BLACK = java.awt.Color.BLACK.getRGB();
final int WHITE = java.awt.Color.WHITE.getRGB();
for(int x = 0; x < wid; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < hgt; y++) {
        boolean val = array[x*wid + y];
        image.setRGB(x,y, val ? BLACK : WHITE);
    }
}
```

I probably could have used a binary image there. This is what I knew offhand :) I'm sure you can tinker with it to change the formatting.

Then you need to convert it to Base64

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
String imageText = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
```

Then, you need to spit out some HTML that references that base 64:

```
String html = "<img src=\"data:image/bmp;" + imageText + "\" alt=\"Random booleans\">";
```

And spit that html out on your page and you should be all set!